# On bounds for the kth term of a recursive sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{u_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ be such that
$$u_{t+1} \le q u_t + \epsilon, \quad 0 \le q < 1, \epsilon >0  $$
for all $t$, then for fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$ 
$$u_{k} \le \frac{\epsilon}{1-q}  + q^k\left( u_0 - \frac{\epsilon }{1-q} \right)$$

This little statement tells us that the sequence $\{u_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$  converges geometrically into the neighborhood around $u_k$ of radius $ \epsilon / (1-q)$ with ratio $q$. The way to prove it is simply to define $v_t := u_t - \epsilon / (1-q)$, and the statement becomes obvious.

Is there a similar statement in this vein for a sequence $\{u\}_{ t \in \mathbb{N} }$ such that

$$u_{t+1} \le q u_t + q_1 u_{t-1} + \epsilon, \quad 0 \le q+ q_1 < 1, \epsilon >0 $$
?

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the second equation is not correct.  The $u$'s will converge to $0$, not to a neighborhood of any given $u_k$.  In particular, $u_0$ could be very large and positive but at some point all the later $u$s could be $0$ or even hugely negative.

The same idea happens with the second equation.  The condition is not on the sum $q+q_1$ but the roots of the characteristic equation $r^2=qr+q_1$.  As long as both of them are less than $1$ in absolute value things will work as you expect.  There will be two solutions to the [recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), but the one with the smaller absolute value of the root will die away.

Comment: Why will the $u$'s converge to $0$? I'm pretty sure the $u$ sequence could be unbounded for large $\epsilon$ no?

Comment: In your original equation the $q^k$ will take the second term to zero regardless of how large $u_0$ and $\epsilon$ are.  The first term will remain.  In the two term recurrence the same thing happens as long as both roots are inside the unit circle.

Comment: I finally understand, could I have a reference for the statement "as long as both of them are less than 1 things will work as you expect"? what is the formal proposition connected to this statement?

Comment: If the roots of the characteristic equation are $r,s$, the solutions to the homogeneous recurrence are $ar^n+bs^n$.  You can verify that by plugging in to the recurrence.  Then if $|r|,|s| \lt 1$ the powers will go to zero.

Comment: I am still missing some detail since in my example we are talking about an inequality and not an equation. How would I use the solution to the homogeneous recurrence?

Comment: That bounds the second term in your inequality.  Because of the variables I am prompted to think of $\epsilon$ as small and $u_0$ as much larger.  The point is that you wind up close to $0$ after a bunch of steps.  The first term gives a range around $0$ that the iteration will stay within.

Comment: Yes that I finally understood so thanks a lot for that! My question is rather simpler: I was wondering how I can explicitly bound the second term with the solution to the homogeneous recurrence? Why does it bound?